# vim unite plugin recreate

Tags: vim, vim-plugin, unite.vim

I'm using Vim with the Unite plugin.

I have a key mapping in my vimrc file like so,

`nnoremap <Leader>t :Unite -start-insert file_rec<CR>`

And it works as expected. Only problem is, when I create a new file in the directory and try to search with t the new file doesn't show up. I guess I need to recreate the index that Unite uses for quickly searching the file. I'm not even sure if Unite uses such an index. It's just my guess.

But is there a way to make Unite show the newly created file when I search for it?

Comment: Unite's issue tracker is [that way](https://github.com/Shougo/unite.vim/issues?direction=desc&sort=created&state=open) and Unite's documentation is there: `:help unite`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the [plugin's documentation](https://github.com/Shougo/unite.vim/blob/master/doc/unite.txt#L3447):

> ```
> Q: Some files are not showing up in file_rec(/async) candidates. What's up
> with that?
>
> A: You need to update the cache. Press |<Plug>(unite_redraw)| (<C-l>) when
> unite is focused.
> ```